# What are the ways to put multiple string keys in couchbase in faster way ? I do not see bulkPut() like bulkGet() for couchbase client

Tags: couchbase, bulk

What are the ways to put multiple string keys in `couchbase` in faster way ?
I do not see `bulkPut()` like `bulkGet()` for `couchbase` client .

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Comment: There is an open enhancement request https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/SPY-126 for Java Couchbase client SDK

Answer (score 0):

For Couchbase Java SDK there is an open enhancement https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/SPY-126 to add this functionality.

However, its possible to do "batch" insert:

```
// Insert them in one batch, waiting until the last one is done.
Observable
    .from(documents)
    .flatMap(new Func1<JsonDocument, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<JsonDocument> call(final JsonDocument docToInsert) {
            return bucket.async().insert(docToInsert);
        }
    })
    .last()
    .toBlocking()
    .single();
```

And batch read:

```
while(true) {
    int docsToLoad = 10;
    Observable
        .range(0, docsToLoad)
        .flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(Integer i) {
                return bucket.async().get("doc-"+i);
            }
        })
        .toList()
        .toBlocking()
        .single();
}
```

See more on [bulk operations](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.0/documents-bulk.html)

For Node.js client set-multi is suppoerted: http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-node-client-1.2.1/Connection.html#setMulti

Comment: since OP is talking about `bulkGet()` method, he's probably using the 1.4 SDK... so note that this `Observable`-based method is valid for the 2.0 generation (which is under `java-client` in maven instead of couchbase-client)